# open file in jsp using servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to open a file using java code (servlet)

in my jsp file I have a button with will call a java code in order to open a file in my web application ,

I have this code in my page jsp

```
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:action_consultDoc()"
                        value="<util:message         key="test.action.consultDoc.title"/>" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function action_consultDoc() {

            documentService.consultDoc(Ext.getCmp('userId').getValue(),  {
                callback : function(responseEntity) {

                }
});
    </script>
```

and in my code java I have

```
public class documentService{

    public void consultDoc(String userid) {
.//here is the code of   c
            byte[] file= c.execute(connector, doc);

// I have a file in this format : byte[]
//here I should call a methode get of servlet

}
}
```

I try with this code without succes

```
 public class documentService{

        public void consultDoc(String userid) {
    .//here is the code of   c
                byte[] file= c.execute(connector, doc);

    // I have a file in this format : byte[]
    //here I should call a methode get of servlet
HttpServletResponse response;
 response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream();
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
           out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't flushed or closed your output stream i.e. `out.flush()`

Comment: Although I agree with you, the servlet container should be doing that.

Comment: but I have error null point exception in this line  response.setHeader("Expires", "0");  I think that I should modify the function consultDoc